# Изменение цвета нажатой кнопки в зависимости от условий

Tags: android, вёрстка, button

Требуется менять цвет нажатой кнопки `ToggleButton` в зависимости от условий. Например, при нажатии в правильный момент цвет нажатой кнопки - зеленый, в неправильный - красный. Как такое можно осуществить?
Через селектор могу задать лишь один цвет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете два селектора . С красным и зеленым цветом . Далее в зависимости от условий применяете к кнопке бэкграунд нужного цвета .

```
if (условие) toggleButton.setBackground(@drawable/green_background);
else toggleButton.setBackground(@drawable/red_background);
```

Или то же самое, в профиль:

```
 toggleButton.setBackground((условие) ? @drawable/green_backgroung : @drawable/red_background);
```

Возможно вам больше подойдут почти аналогичные методы  `setBackgroundResource (int resid)` или `setBackgroundColor (int color)` логика использования которых аналогично тому , что выше .